# Get the right constructor by parameter name

Tags: java, reflection

I am try to use reflect to create some instance through the json configuration:

config.json:

```
{
    "clazz":com.kk.Manager",
    "args":{
        "path":"/home/kk/a.txt",
        "scale":1
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
packge com.kk;
public class Manager{
    private File file;
    private int scale;
    public Manager(String path,int scale){
        this.file = new File(path)
        this.scale=scale;
        //other initialization work omitted
    }
}

private static Object buildObject(String clazz, JSONObject args) {
    Object instance;
    try {
        Class clas = Class.forName(clazz);

        if (args == null) {
            instance = clas.newInstance();
        } else {
            Class[] pamas = new Class[args.length()];
            Object[] vals = new Object[args.length()];

            Iterator<String> parameterIt = args.keys();

            int i = 0;
            while (parameterIt.hasNext()) {
                String fd = parameterIt.next();
                Object val = args.get(fd);
                pamas[i] = val.getClass();
                vals[i] = val;
                i++;
            }


            instance = clas.getConstructor(pamas).newInstance(vals);
        }
        return instance;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

After I parse the json config file, I will call it like this:

```
String clazz = parent.getString("clazz");
JSONObject args = parent.getJSONObject("args")
buildObject(clazz,args);
```

While the code throw error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.kk.Manager.<init>(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
```

It seem that the constructor of `Manager` is called with parameters in wrong order.

After google, it seems that the order of keys in  a JSONObject is undefined.

So I wonder if I can get the constructor by the parameter name, something like:

```
Class cls = Class.forName(clazz);
cls.getConstructor("path","scale");
```

Or if not, how can I fix this without add the setter method?

Comment: Based on your `JSON` request, how do you know what type the value is?  Have you verified `val.getClass()` matches your expectations?  It would appear that that `args.keys()` doesn't gurenetee the order of the parameters

Comment: Unless you tell the compiler to keep the parameter names in there, they will not exist and in any case, you won't be able to get them through reflection. You will need to go through the bytecode.

Comment: Consider getting all the constructors and looking for a suitable one?`getConstructors()`

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse: Sounds like an acceptable idea, I will have a try.